# How to display multiple images from a folder in python?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, opencv, imshow, python

I'm trying to use k-means to cluster images.

I have a folder in my documents that has 30 images in it. First, i'm trying to just read in each image before starting the clustering code. But, for some reason the following code only outputs one image:

```
img_dir="C:/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB/attempt6images"
data_path=os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files=glob.glob(data_path)
data=[]
for f1 in files:
    img=cv2.imread(f1)
    data.append(img)
       
plt.imshow(img)
```

I want to see that all 30 images have been stored in the code so that I can later cluster them. How come only one image is displayed when I run this code?

Comment: are you doing this in a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.image import imread
folder = 'train/'     #folder where your photos are store
# plot first few images
for i in range(9):
    # define subplot
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    x= folder + 'cat.' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    # load image pixels
    image = imread(x)
    # plot raw pixel data
    pyplot.imshow(image)
```

## show the figure

pyplot.show()

Answer (score 0):

Iam a bit late
Try the following code:

```
img_dir="C:/Users/User/Documents/MATLAB/attempt6images"
all_files=os.listdir(img_dir)
data_path = [os.path.join(img_dir + "/" + i) for i in all_files]
k=0
for i in data_path:
  k=k+1
  plt.subplot(3,2,k) 
  plt.imshow(imread(i))
plt.show()
```

Note :If you are displaying 6 images then subplots will have first 2 parameters as (3,2) i.e 3 columns and 2 rows.
For 4 images it will be (2,2)